# Usable Ram Memory in Windows 7 shows less

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I have currently upgraded my OS from Windows XP 32 bit to windows 7 64 bit ultimate and my installed RAM shows as 4 GB ( 3.05 GB Usable ). Can you please advise why the Usable RAM memory showing less in system properties?

My motherboard, processor and ram specifications as follows..
AMD 3.4 GHz FM2 A4-5300 Processor
MSI FM2-A55M-E33 Motherboard
Corsair DDR3 4 GB - DDR3 RAM, 1600 MHZ

Comment: please take effort to search things before asking a question

Comment: @Sickest sure.. apologies for posting a duplicate question.. thank you .. i believe that my bios is not updated.. Is this the reason usable memory is showing less?

Comment: I have no idea really, take a look at the other answer first and see if that helps your situation.

Comment: Make sure the motherboard BIOS update to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft:

This is expected behavior on computers that are running Windows 7. The reduction in available system memory depends on the configuration of the following:
The devices that are installed in the computer and the memory that is reserved by those devices
The ability of the motherboard to handle memory
The System BIOS version and settings
The version of Windows 7 that is installed (For example, Windows 7 Starter Edition only supports 2 GB of installed memory.)
Other system settings

EDIT:
For example, if you have a video card that has 256 MB of on-board memory, that memory must be mapped within the first 4 GB of address space. If 4 GB of system memory is already installed, part of that address space must be reserved by the graphics memory mapping. Graphics memory mapping overwrites a part of the system memory. These conditions reduce the total amount of system memory that is available to the operating system.

For more info:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978610

Comment: `to windows 7 64 bit ultimate`

Comment: This is not limited to 32-bit windows. You can read the article linked and it will show you that it can happen in 64 bit versions as well.

Comment: `Expect behavior` is a bit dramatic. You also reference starter edition which isn't relevant, this isn't an OS issue. lastly... you're just reiteration the linked url in the first comment.

Comment: I did not reference Starter Edition. It was used as an example from a direct quote from the Microsoft Article. If there is anything wrong with that, then the first quote you linked referenced Vista which also has nothing to do with this question. I linked a direct Microsoft article that address his concern (it discusses all versions of 7) and also provides possible solutions.